# TextWatcher - addTextChangedListener add several listeners

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I need to add some text update for an edit text after a user enters in input. I thought about using another TextWatcher to existing ones. Is there a way to be sure my TextWatcher occurs before the other one that was used (when I have several TextWatchers)

Answer (score 1):

They should trigger in the order that you added them. But this is not guaranteed. If you need a guarantee just chain them manually i.e. have one 'SuperTextWatcher' that delegates the event to the others. See [code where the watchers are called](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/TextView.java#7674)